# something wrong with this jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There is a debugging `syntax` error, but I can’t see it! im a bit of a newbie, so excuse my code!!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     /* fetch elements and stop form event */
     $("form.follow-form").submit(function (e) {
        /* stop event */
        e.preventDefault();
        /* "on request" */
        $(this).find('i').addClass('active');
        /* send ajax request */
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_more.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ul.statuses").append(html);
                    $("form.follow-form").remove();
                }
            });
            else {
                $(".morebox").html('The End');
            }
            return false;
     });
});
```

Comment: syntax error on netbeans its showing red lines! and please have manners theres no need to be cheeky? your not obliged to answer the question! thank you

Comment: @getaway - I suggest you learn to write a correctly formulated and unstandable question, then you wouldn't get 'cheeky' comments. Read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints.

Comment: @getaway -- wow. ask for help, then complain when people ask for pertinent information you've omitted. Now that's chuzpah.

Comment: where is this else comming without if?

Comment: @tvvanfosson, i just dnt appreciate someone being cheeky, theres no need to say `ugh` like im stupid or something, anyway im sorry for my mistake and im sorry for being a beginner, i will make sure i will come back when im more advanced. thanks to everyone that helped!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* fetch elements and stop form event */
    $("form.follow-form").submit(function(e) { /* stop event */
        e.preventDefault(); /* "on request" */
        $(this).find('i').addClass('active'); /* send ajax request */
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_more.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("ul.statuses").append(html);
                $("form.follow-form").remove();
            }
        });
        $(".morebox").html('The End');
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 10):

You’ve got an `else`, but no `if`.

Here’s the code with some proper indentation — indentation makes the code much easier to understand, so you spot errors more quickly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    /* fetch elements and stop form event */
    $("form.follow-form").submit(function (e) {

        /* stop event */
        e.preventDefault();

        /* "on request" */
        $(this).find('i').addClass('active');

        /* send ajax request */
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_more.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("ul.statuses").append(html);
                $("form.follow-form").remove();
            }
        });


======> /* HERE’S THE ELSE WITHOUT AN IF */

        else {
            $(".morebox").html('The End');
        }

        return false;
    });

});
```